# Questions about Rust lifetime

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to implement a memory pool based on `TypedArena`. Here's a simplified version of my original code:

```
#![feature(rustc_private)]
extern crate arena;
use arena::TypedArena;

pub struct MemoryPool {
    arena: TypedArena<Vec<u8>>,
    bytes_allocated: usize,
}

impl MemoryPool {
    pub fn consume(&mut self, buf: Vec<u8>) -> &[u8] {
        self.bytes_allocated += buf.capacity();
        self.arena.alloc(buf)
    }
}

pub struct ByteArray<'a> {
    data: &'a [u8],
}

impl<'a> ByteArray<'a> {
    pub fn set_data(&mut self, data: &'a [u8]) {
        self.data = data;
    }
}

pub struct S<'a> {
    pool: &'a mut MemoryPool,
}

impl<'a> S<'a> {
    pub fn write(&mut self, buffer: &mut ByteArray<'a>) {
        let v = vec!();
        let data = self.pool.consume(v);
        buffer.set_data(data);
    }
}
```

However, the compiler complains about the line: `let data = self.pool.consume(v);`:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> <anon>:34:26
   |
34 |     let data = self.pool.consume(v);
   |                          ^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 32:54...
  --> <anon>:32:55
   |
32 |     pub fn write(&mut self, buffer: &mut ByteArray<'a>) {
   |  _______________________________________________________^ starting here...
33 | |     let v = vec!();
34 | |     let data = self.pool.consume(v);
35 | |     buffer.set_data(data);
36 | |   }
   | |___^ ...ending here
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> <anon>:34:16
   |
34 |     let data = self.pool.consume(v);
   |                ^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the body at 32:54...
  --> <anon>:32:55
   |
32 |     pub fn write(&mut self, buffer: &mut ByteArray<'a>) {
   |  _______________________________________________________^ starting here...
33 | |     let v = vec!();
34 | |     let data = self.pool.consume(v);
35 | |     buffer.set_data(data);
36 | |   }
   | |___^ ...ending here
note: ...so that types are compatible (expected &mut ByteArray<'_>, found &mut ByteArray<'a>)
  --> <anon>:35:12
   |
35 |     buffer.set_data(data);
   |            ^^^^^^^^
```

My question is:

1. **Why `data` does not have lifetime `'a`**? I'm thinking that since `pool` has lifetime `a` and `consume` returns the same lifetime as `self`, it should have lifetime `'a`.
2. **What's the best way to make this code work as intended?** Basically I want to allocate new bytes and adjust their lifetime to be the same as the memory pool. I know I can use `TypedArena` directly since `alloc` does not take a `mut` reference. However I really want to track other information such as `bytes_allocated`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's tackle this step by step:

```
cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref
```

"autoref" describes the process of building the right reference for the `self` argument of a method. The compiler is unable to find a reference with the right lifetime to call `consume()`. Why is it unable?

```
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 32:54...
  --> <anon>:32:55
   |
32 |     pub fn write(&mut self, buffer: &mut ByteArray<'a>) {
   |  _______________________________________________________^ starting here...
33 | |     let v = vec!();
34 | |     let data = self.pool.consume(v);
35 | |     buffer.set_data(data);
36 | |   }
   | |___^ ...ending here
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> <anon>:34:16
   |
34 |     let data = self.pool.consume(v);
   |                ^^^^^^^^^
```

The "anonymous lifetime #1" refers to the lifetime of `&mut self`. This note is just saying: we can't pass a reference with a lifetime greater than the lifetime of `self` into `consume()`: then `consume()` would think that its `self` argument lives longer than it actually does.

```
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a
```

This is the rule you already expected to be applied. But where is the problem now? Well: the lifetime of `&mut self` (anonymous lifetime #1) could life *shorter* than `'a`! That's all! And we can fix it quite easily:

```
impl<'a> S<'a> {
    pub fn write<'b: 'a>(&'b mut self, buffer: &mut ByteArray<'a>) {
        //      ^^^^^^^^  ^^
        ...
    }
}
```

Here we just name the previously anonymous lifetime #1 to be able to bound it, saying that it has to *outlive* `'a` (live longer than `'a`).

Comment: Thanks. I think the confusion I had was that `self.pool` has lifetime of `self` instead of `pool`, with `pool` being mutable. This is not intuitive as there's a lifetime annotation `'a` attached to `pool. To fix the code, do you have other suggestion rather than adding a `'b` for `self`? This doesn't work for my original code as struct `S` is expected to live shorter than `'a`.

Comment: @ChaoSun that's not possible. The `MemoryPool` can't return a reference that lives longer than itself and similarly, `S` can't return something that references something that lives longer than itself, and `S::pool` lives exactly as long as `S`. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve.