# Function refered from the stored in struct does not give the ownership up

Tags: function, rust, lifetime

I'm writing a algorithm testbench to compare performance in Rust.

I want to store a bunch of function for an algorithm in a struct, and apply those functions to some data.
When I call the function by reference, which stored in the struct, I couldn't figure out the lifetime.

```rust
struct Alg<'a, 'b, 'c> {
    alg1: &'c Fn(&'a A<'a>, &'b B<'b>) -> usize,
    alg2: &'c Fn(&'a A<'a>, &'b B<'b>) -> String,
}

struct A<'a> {
    a_str: &'a str,
}

struct B<'b> {
    b_str: &'b str,
}

fn concat<'a, 'b>(_a: &'a A<'a>, _b: &'b B<'b>) -> String {
    _a.a_str.to_string() + &_b.b_str.to_string()
}

fn length<'a, 'b>(_a: &'a A<'a>, _b: &'b B<'b>) -> usize {
    _a.a_str.len() + _b.b_str.len()
}

fn run1<'a, 'b, 'c>(_a: &'a A<'a>, _b: &'b B<'b>, _f_c: &'c Alg<'a, 'b, 'c>) {
    println!("{}", &(_f_c.alg1)(_a, _b));
}

fn run2<'a, 'b, 'c>(_a: &'a A<'a>, _b: &'b B<'b>, _f_c: &'c Alg<'a, 'b, 'c>) {
    println!("{}", &(_f_c.alg2)(_a, _b));
}

fn main() {
    let f_struct = Alg {
        alg1: &length,
        alg2: &concat,
    };

    for _i in 0..2 {
        let a_str = "ABC";
        let a = A { a_str: a_str };
        for _j in 0..2 {
            let b_str = "BCD";
            let b = B { b_str: b_str };
            println!("{}", concat(&a, &b)); // This works
            println!("{}", (f_struct.alg1)(&a, &b)); // I expect that `concat` or `length` in `f_struct` may finished borrowing `a` or `b' here, as like as `println!("{}",concat(&a,&b))`
                                                     //run1(&a,&b,&f_struct);
                                                     //run2(&a,&b,&f_struct);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get an error message like:

```
error[E0597]: `a` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:43:44
   |
43 |             println!("{}", (f_struct.alg1)(&a, &b)); // I expect that `concat` or `length` in `f_struct` may finished borrowing `a` or `b' here, as like as `println!("{}",concat(&a,&b))`
   |                            --------------- ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                            |
   |                            borrow used here, in later iteration of loop
...
47 |     }
   |     - `a` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0597]: `b` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:43:48
   |
43 |             println!("{}", (f_struct.alg1)(&a, &b)); // I expect that `concat` or `length` in `f_struct` may finished borrowing `a` or `b' here, as like as `println!("{}",concat(&a,&b))`
   |                            ---------------     ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                            |
   |                            borrow used here, in later iteration of loop
...
46 |         }
   |         - `b` dropped here while still borrowed
```

What is the difference between `println!("{}",concat(&a,&b))` and `println!("{}",(f_struct.alg1)(&a,&b))`?

I thought that I have to indicate something that the function no more borrows the value with lifetime `'a` or `'b`, but I couldn't find it from rust-by-example or rust-book.

I've tried to apply coercion like `'c: 'a + 'b`, but this seems not to help.

These questions are related, but not so clear to me.

- [Rust lifetime error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204134/rust-lifetime-error)
- [Rust lifetime error expected concrete lifetime but found bound lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847331/rust-lifetime-error-expected-concrete-lifetime-but-found-bound-lifetime)
- [Questions about Rust lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43223497/questions-about-rust-lifetime)

#### Point

- I want to store functions in the struct

  - I could try another way like not to store functions in the struct
  - But I want to understand the reason when this approach is impossible

Comment: Unrelated to your actual problem, but you should take a look at [`cargo bench`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.12.1/book/benchmark-tests.html)

Comment: Please use `cargo fmt` (for example at the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/)) to format your code according to the rust standards so it is easier to read for everybody.

Comment: @hellow Thanks for your advices too much. But `rustup` says that `rustfmt` is not able to use for 'x86_64-pc-windows-msvc'....

Comment: Have you tried `rustup component add rustfmt`?

Comment: Yes, it returns the message when I run it on a windows machine.

Comment: Try `rustup self update`, `rustup update` and then `rustup component add rustfmt`

Comment: @hellow Sorry for late response. My `rustup` is `rustup 1.16.0 (beab5ac2b 2018-12-06)`, and update it. But I still get a message: `error: toolchain 'stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc' does not contain component 'rustfmt' for target 'x86_64-pc-windows-msvc'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Quick solution

You have too many lifetime specifiers. Remove the lifetimes for references in your function parameters. Eg. replace `alg1: &'c Fn(&'a A<'a>, &'b B<'b>) -> usize` with `alg1: &'c Fn(&A<'a>, &B<'b>) -> usize` (and similar changes to all functions ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=84fc5ae01c6b3937d113427d1772621d)).

## Explanation

First, let's simplify your code a bit and rename some of the lifetimes so that we know which one we are talking about:

```
struct Alg<'Alg_a, 'Alg_b> {
    alg1: &'Alg_b Fn(&'Alg_a A<'Alg_a>) -> usize,
}

struct A<'A_a> {
    a_str: &'A_a str,
}

fn length<'L_a>(a: &'L_a A<'L_a>) -> usize {
    a.a_str.len()
}

fn main() {
    let f_struct = Alg {
        alg1: &length,
    };

    for _i in 0..2 {
        let a_str = "ABC";
        let a = A { a_str: a_str };
        println!("{}", length (&a)); // This works
        println!("{}", (f_struct.alg1) (&a)); // This doesn't
    }
}
```

You can check on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dca909084ba6b0c4e45d8696d75dfb8b) that this exhibits the same error as your code.

When you call `(f_struct.alg1)(&a)`, the compiler tries to find good values for the lifetimes `'Alg_a` and `'Alg_b` associated with `f_struct`. Since `f_struct` is defined outside the loop, then those lifetimes must be the same for **all** iterations of the loop. However `Alg::alg1` is defined as `Fn(&'Alg_a …)` which means that `'Alg_a` must be the lifetime of the parameter `a` which is only valid for **a single** loop iteration. Hence the error.

By not specifying the lifetime of the parameter, I allow the compiler to choose different lifetimes for the parameter `a` and for `'Alg_a`, and in particular to choose a different lifetime for the parameter each time the function is called. So the lifetime for the parameter can be limited to a single loop iteration while `'Alg_a` may be longer:

```
struct Alg<'Alg_a, 'Alg_b> {
    alg1: &'Alg_b Fn(&A<'Alg_a>) -> usize,
}

struct A<'A_a> {
    a_str: &'A_a str,
}

fn length<'L_a>(a: &A<'L_a>) -> usize {
    a.a_str.len()
}

fn main() {
    let f_struct = Alg {
        alg1: &length,
    };

    for _i in 0..2 {
        let a_str = "ABC";
        let a = A { a_str: a_str };
        println!("{}", length (&a)); // This works
        println!("{}", (f_struct.alg1) (&a)); // Now this does too
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=524f046b64afde8b2ce11eed74c0cb93)

### Why does calling `length` directly work?

When calling `length` directly, the compiler only needs to determine the lifetime `'L_a` and there is nothing that requires this lifetime to last for more than a single loop iteration, so there is no conflict.

### Note

As noted by @VikramFugro, this only work because `a_str = "ABC"` creates a slice with a `'static` lifetime which can be shrunk down to `'Alg_a` or `'L_a` as required. Using a dynamic string (`let a_str = String::from("ABC")`) [does not work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=299f223ae42ab4316e48ea7dd77e4b21). We need to declare `alg1` as `&'Alg_b for<'F_a> Fn(&A<'F_a>) -> usize` instead of using the `'Alg_a` lifetime on the `Alg` struct:

```
struct Alg<'Alg_b> {
    alg1: &'Alg_b for<'F_a> Fn(&A<'F_a>) -> usize,
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b27f889b484dbe5856a88e9d588b5a56)

Additionally, Rust 2018 allows us to use an anonymous lifetime `'_` instead of the `for<'a> …` syntax, for example `&'Alg_b Fn(&A<'_>) -> usize` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=43a4ebe47a1a2656a160b0d605a5082e)).

Comment: Note that in some cases simply removing the lifetimes in the `Fn` signature is not enough. A trait bound like `Fn(&T) -> &U` implicitly gets translated into `for<'a> Fn(&'a T) -> &'a U` by the compiler, using a _higher rank trait bound_ and the rules of lifetime elision. If the function signature is `Fn(&T, &T) -> &U`, though, lifetime elision is not possible, and you need to specify the HRTB explicitly. See also [the HRTB chapter in the Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought that I have to add all the lifetime identifiers.

Comment: @SvenMarnach note that I only said to remove the lifetimes for the function _parameters._ Return values should keep their explicit lifetimes.

Comment: @QuietJoon it would be possible to add all the lifetime identifiers, but then you need to use different lifetimes as required. E.g. `for<'F_a> Fn(&'F_a A<'Alg_a>)` so that the compiler will know that `'F_a` and `'Alg_a` may be different.

Comment: Also please note that, `let a_str = "ABC"` has a `'static` lifetime, and `'static`  in this can case can be shrunk down to `'Alg_a` (or `'L_a`). For eg. [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=299f223ae42ab4316e48ea7dd77e4b21) would not work.  Rust 2018 allows anonymous lifetimes (`'_`), especially where elisions could be confusing. We can use it to our advantage to fix this here. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=43a4ebe47a1a2656a160b0d605a5082e)

Comment: @VikramFugro thanks for the comments, edited the answer.

Comment: @Jmb It rarely makes sense to keep the lifetime for a return value while removing the explicit lifetime for the arguments.

Comment: @SvenMarnach ok, so what I meant is: “_you should remove lifetimes for the function parameters, unless the return value is a reference that should have the same lifetime as one of the parameters or unless more than one parameter should share the same lifetime between them, in which case you should keep the lifetimes for those parameters and only remove the other parameter lifetimes_”. But that's a bit of a mouthful so I concentrated on what's relevant for the question.